# DTSX package runs correctly from SSIS store but not SQL Server Agent

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

I am relatively new to SSIS packages Package is a File system task to rename and move a file.
Package runs correctly from SSIS store but whe I run it as asql server agent job it doesnt move or rename file but shows successful.  What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing the package from the store, you are likely executing the package under your own domain credentials, which probably have permissions on the folders/files impacted by the package.

When executing from the server agent, it likely does not have those same permissions on the files/folders.  That would be the first thing I would check, but having additional information as to the resources being manipulated and user accounts used could potentially shed more light on the situation.

Comment: Overthinking...thanks you answer was enough to get me on the right track